# The old launch.json can't debugging cpp in VSC though it used to be

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I buy a new computer recently,and redownload Visual Studio Code to my computer since I find it can not work in my portable disk from my old computer.When I finish my working by rebuild the C++ and runner extension,download mingw64 and path it as I have done in my old computer.Then I use VCS to redirect
myprogramming file in my portable disk and check if it can work normally,then the weird thing happeded.

I find .vscode file in myprogramming file can't debug my cpp any more though it had work when I programming in my old computer,I checked my mingw64 path and find it's not problem,and rebuild the launch.json in .vscode file(gdb.exe) but the debugger still not working.and I can't find anymore effective solution from Microsoft tutoriel.So I hope someone can answer my confusion and I can't appericiate any more.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try generating a new `launch.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

One solution may solve your issue.

### How to configure `tasks.json` and `launch.json` from VSCode

You don't need to do any type of coding for this, just follow the steps:

1. Delete `tasks.json` and `launch.json` located in `.vscode` folder
2. Press `F5` (debugging shortcut) again focusing on that C program file, you'll see something like:

[image: Automatic launch configuration wizard]

3. Select your compiler which is `GCC` (since you're trying to debug a C program and ensure the compiler is installed into your system).
4. You'll be prompted to select a configuration (assuming selected option: GCC), you'll get `launch.json` created automatically by VSCode as shown below:

[image: Successful creation of launch.json]

> **Note:** Keep the `preLaunchTask` configuration in your mind (located at the bottom-most of the config).

5. As soon as you press `F5` again (this time, for creation of `tasks.json`) you'll get something shown below, simply select **Configure Tasks**:

[image: Required error to configure tasks.json]

6. Now, you'll be redirected into `tasks.json`, edit the `label` to the name you've selected in § 4 (remember that `name`). In other words, launch's `preLaunchTask` and tasks' `label` should be the same. Process shown below:

[image: Renaming the label for debugging]

And now, you can make a successful debug. A working example:

[image: A successful example of debugging]

Comment: Solved as you said.I find the problem is launch's preLaunchTask and tasks' label is not in same.Thanks.

Comment: @Tracker647 that's why you need to make them same.