# VSCode c++ debugging unhandled exception

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I try to debug my c program in vscode it gives me error stating that "windowsdebuglauncher.exe has stopped working" following this message in console:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.FormattableStringFactory' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at WindowsDebugLauncher.Program.ParseDebugExeArgs(String line)
   at WindowsDebugLauncher.Program.Main(String[] argv)
```

When try to debug I run default configurations automatically created by vscode (so basically my launch.json is almost empty and tasks.json default). Compiler: gcc, Debugger: gdb. I assume this issue comes because something is not installed on my OS(Windows 8.1). What may cause this thing and how to fix it?

**UPD:**
My tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "sprintf.c",
                "s21_string.c",
                "s21_string_io.c",
                "s21_string_special.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lcheck"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

My launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [ 
        // {
        //     "name": "default",
        //     "type": "cppvsdbg",
        //     "request": "launch",
        //     "program": "src\\test.exe",
        //     "args": [],
        //     "stopAtEntry": true,
        //     "environment": [],
        //     "console": "externalTerminal",
        //     "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        //     "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        // }
    ]
}
```

If i uncomment these lines, it will successfully build file but debug will not be launched and no error message appears and debug console will be empty.

Comment: From my assumption, this is a user-end problem. Also, `launch.json` and `tasks.json` are not supposed to be empty to proceed to debug. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832212/11471113) solution and see if it works.

Comment: @RohanBari no this was not the issue, I have correctly configured launch.json and tasks.json. I assume I have to update my question with these files if it will shred some light on problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how, but i fixed the issue. Despair of finding debugger I ran gdb manually in vscode terminal and then ran it through vscode and it seem to work.