# Visual Studio code unhandled exception

Tags: c++, c, vscode-debugger

Started to set up VS Code for C/C++, Installed MinGW, etc. Everything works fine except debugging.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.FormattableStringFactory' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at WindowsDebugLauncher.Program.ParseDebugExeArgs(String line)
   at WindowsDebugLauncher.Program.Main(String[] argv)
```

VS Code gives this every time I try to debug

I tried to change something in launch.json but its ok. How can I fix this error?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Запустить",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Включить автоматическое форматирование для gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Задать для варианта приложения дизассемблирования значение Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Here is launch.json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124841/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-error Might be helpful to you

Comment: try removing pretty printing, looks like a bug in VSCode

Comment: The [VSCode config guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) recommends using MSYS2 to install MinGW, so you get the latest version.

Comment: Updated to latest version and  nothing changed @BoP

Comment: checked pretty printing, its disabled @AhmedAEK

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/72255585/11107541. exact same error message. different launch config type though. but if it works, let's close this as a duplicate.